# How to get formulas to do the calculations

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column  from A1:A398 in a Google spreadsheet. Each cell either has an "f" or is blank. I want to count how many of each there are. In row 399, 400 and 401 I put the following formulas

```
=counta(A1:A398)
=COUNTIF(A1:A398,"f")
=COUNTBLANK(A1:A398)
```

However the formulas aren't doing anything. I expected the counting to take place and the value to be displayed in the cell once I hit return (as it did for me in Excel when I used to have it), however, Google spreadsheets is just showing me the formula. Based on what I've told you and how I wrote the formulas, is there a reason why they aren't  calculating?

Comment: Can't replicate: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IXKubwQj9XyboqwY8t47mHGqD7BZwF3VATZwlY6VyTM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have `All Formulas` checked in the `View` menu.  Go to the `View` menu or press Ctrl + ` (backtick) to toggle the view on/off - you should then see it alternate between the formulas and the calculated values.

Comment: Depending on the version you use, this setting might also be on the ribbon "Formulas".